# Error while trying to execute an example mirah script?

Tags: mirah

```
$ ../bin/mirah -e fib.mirah 
Inference Error:
Cannot find static method fib() on DashE
DashE:1: Cannot find static method fib() on DashE
```

Got this while trying to run the mirah script that is grabbed from the examples folder. How can I fix this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I should use mirahc instead of mirah. So... fixed.